# Is it possible to determine, in Python, whether two partitions are on the same disk?

Tags: python, windows

I'm using Windows right now but am interested in the answer for any operating systems.

I'm writing a program that hashes a large number of files stored on multiple disks, each of which is split into multiple partitions. For example, Disk #1 has partitions C, D, and E, while Disk #2 has partitions F and G, and Disk #3 has partition H.

I would like to save some time by hashing files in parallel: three threads or processes for the three disks, so 3 files are going at once but only one from each disk. However, I'm not sure how to determine which physical disk a given file is on. (Within my code, that is. I could obviously hardcode it today, but I'm interested in making this re-usable and general.)

Is this information exposed by the operating system in a way that I can access?

Comment: You can query the physical disk number or ID with an IOCTL, but this will require PyWin32 or ctypes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `st_dev` part of a `stat` result to determine what device a directory is on. You're looking for directories that are on different devices:

```
import os

print(os.stat('c:\\').st_dev)
print(os.stat('d:\\').st_dev)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to indicate different devices. I just partitioned an SD card creating V and W partitions, and they have two different st_dev values.

Comment: Python 3 uses the volume serial number (VSN) for `st_dev`, which is from the filesystem that's mounted on the volume -- not from the physical disk device and not even directly from the volume device itself (typically a partition on a disk).

Comment: Note that Python's use of the VSN for `st_dev` is  a dubious thing to do because Windows makes no guarantee that the VSN will be unique in the system or even non-zero, but Unix `st_dev` requires uniqueness. For example, for a WebDAV share in Windows, the VSN is always 0. In contrast, a WebDAV mount in Linux has a uniquely generated `st_dev` for a given mount instance.

Comment: Hm, that's unfortunate, sorry - then it would seem you'd need to implement OS API specific solutions for various OSes. I know how to do it from C#, so there's probably a fairly straightforward translation to using Win32 from Python, but obviously that's Windows only. (or you get lucky when looking for someone else who already wrote the library...)